# Understanding EWOULDBLOCK on non blocking sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to access the syslog messages on the router from the remote GUI application. Basically WEB server on the router openes syslog file(/var/log/messages), read all the log messages and try to send it over this WEB socket to client GUI application on user request. Its a non blocking socket. So I observed that when the number of messages are huge(size of send buffer is big), upon calling send() call, it is always returning -1 with error EWOULDBLOCK. I tried to reissue the call many time and the same result followed. Is this implies that send buffer is full on TCP/IP stack ? So how to avoid it ? I even observed that when the send buffer is less, send() is successfully sending data.
Thanks for your replies in advance ?

Comment: If your socket is non-blocking, you need to poll it and respond to "ready to write" events. In the meantime, you need to queue up the data you want to send yourself.

Comment: @Kerrek  Thanks for reply . I am doing the same thing. I am maintaining one fifo and waiting for FD_WRITE events. How much time/conditions will it take to signal this event to user space?

Comment: The TCP/UDP send buffer is of finite size. If you are trying to `send()` messages that are larger that the send buffer, `send()` will always return EWOULDBLOCK. Perhaps trying splitting the log messages into chunks guaranteed not to exceed the TCP/UDP send buffer. You can adjust the size of the buffer (within limits with `setsockopt()`).

Answer (score 2):

You can set the sender buffer to a large size:

```
int                     sendbuf         = -1; /* -1 will give a maximum allowed buffer size you can use any larger number */
rc = setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF,(char *)&sendbuf, sizeof(sendbuf));
if(rc < 0){
          printf(("Setting SO_SNDBUF error, %s",strerror(errno)));
          return -1;
}
```

To avoid EWOULDBLOCK (this errno happens when send buffer is full) you should use iomux (epoll, poll or select)
also, this errno happens when receive buffer is empty when trying to receive.

Comment: There is no such limit. You can send any size data. TCP will packetizing it according to the path MTU but this doesn't affect the sending application in any way.

Comment: @EJP I meant that when you send a messge of datalen>64KB EMSGSIZE takes place .... datalen=65536;databuf = malloc(sizeof(char) * datalen);
                memset(databuf, 0, datalen);
 rc = sendto(sd, databuf,  datalen , 0);

Comment: Only in UDP. There's no mention of UDP in the question. To be accurate, the maximum UDP payload is 65507.

Comment: sorry I should mention that on UDP, yes 65507+28headers=64kb

Comment: Wrong again. 65507+28=65535, not 64kb.  And none of this UDP stuff has any apparent relevant relevance to the question.

Comment: Just remove the part starting 'first'. You could have done that yourself instead of arguing about it.